# How to avoid this java.io.IOException: No space left on device

Tags: java

If my space is full I get sometimes following exception

```
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:282)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1756)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.<init>(ObjectOutputStream.java:230)
```

Is there any way in Java to avoid this. I mean do not call write if no space

Comment: a `try..catch` block should do the trick...

Comment: java.io.IOException is generic I guess, Can be thrown for any other reasons Right !!!

Comment: You can check the messages. In any case, you should make sure you always have enough space.

Comment: It's not practical to reliably avoid getting that error in the first place. If you know how much disk space you need, you can check that the space is available first, but you might still get the error if another program is also writing a file. Most programs just deal with it in some fashion when they get the error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java 7 NIO offers the [`FileStore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html) class to check the available size

```
Path p = Paths.get("/your/file"); // where you want to write
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();
Iterable<FileStore> iterable = fileSystem.getFileStores();

Iterator<FileStore> it = iterable.iterator(); // iterate the FileStore instances
while(it.hasNext()) {
    FileStore fileStore = it.next();
    long sizeAvail = fileStore.getUsableSpace(); // or maybe getUnallocatedSpace()
    if (Files.getFileStore(p).equals(fileStore) { // your Path belongs to this FileStore
        if (sizeAvail > theSizeOfBytesYouWantToWrite) {
            // do your thing
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you can still get an `IOException` as nothing is atomic and other processes might be using the same disk, so keep that in mind and handle the exception accordingly.

Comment: On Unix-like operating systems, you can also get "No space left on device" if you are trying to create a new file and the filesystem is out of inodes. So you might have to check for free inodes as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the File class [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getTotalSpace%28%29).

These new methods also include:

```
public long getTotalSpace()
public long getFreeSpace()
public long getUsableSpace()
```